# Is it possible to inherit razor markup from a component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm currently trying to abstract away a mechanism to enumerate an IAsyncEnumerable as it becomes available.

I have a base component class that looks roughly like this

```
// EnumerableRazorComponentBase.razor
@typeparam TObject

@if (!(this.enumerationTask?.IsCompleted ?? false))
{
    // Display loading bar
}
```

```
// EnumerableRazorComponentBase.razor.cs
public abstract partial class EnumerableRazorComponentBase<TObject> : ComponentBase
{
    private Task enumerationTask;
    // rest of enumeration logic...
}
```

Now I inherit this base class in a razor component

```
// SomeComponent.razor
@inherits EnumerableRazorComponentBase<IMyInterface>

// other razor markup

@code {
    // rest impl
}
```

`EnumerableRazorComponentBase.razor.cs` is inherited properly and works as expected, but the markup in `EnumerableRazorComponentBase.razor` is not added to the markup of `SomeComponent.razor`.

Is it possible to inherit razor markup from a base class, and if so what am I doing wrong/what am I missing?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to extend/inherit from BlazoredTypeahead and definitely can't re-implement the .razor file (it also calls private methods on its .cs). I keep seeing "try composition instead," but in that scenario I can't figure out how to propagate events from the Typeahead up to my own client.

Comment: Would be great to have an answer to this question !

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible. Just add a call to base.BuildRenderTree like so:

```
// SomeComponent.razor
@inherits EnumerableRazorComponentBase<IMyInterface>

@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

<h2>Additional markup in subclassed component</h2>

@code {
    // rest impl
}
```

Comment: What is `__builder` here? That doesn't resolve for me.

Comment: @Tim The variable `__builder` is the current builder of your `.razor` file. It should be generated automatically and inherited from [ComponentBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for all razor pages.