# Blazor: Show content of parent component in the child component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm struggling with the component inheritance in Blazor. I want to create a base component
`MyComponentBase.razor` which contains the base layout. The `MyComponent.razor` inherits from the `MyComponentBase.razor` component and contains the content.

My problem is that the page in the Blazor app shows only the content of the `MyComponent.razor` component but not the combined content. I couldn't find any example that explains how to do that. Can anyone help?

`MyComponentBase.razor`

```
@inherits ComponentBase

<div>
    <p>My Title</p>
    <p>My SubTitle</p>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

`MyComponent.razor`

```
@inherits MyComponentBase

<p>My Content</p>
```

`MyPage.razor`

```
@page "/page"

<MyComponent/>
```

**Expected result**

```
<div>
    <p>My Title</p>
    <p>My SubTitle</p>    
    <p>My Content</p>
</div>
```

**Actual result**

```
<p>My Content</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to inherit razor markup from a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364187/is-it-possible-to-inherit-razor-markup-from-a-component)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [basic component layout inheritance blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59990832/11683)

Comment: Yes, of course that should be `<MyComponent/>`. It was a typo, I have corrected it. Thank you for the links, I will check them.

Answer (score 2):

When you inherit, you override the RenderTree. Thats why `MyComponent` only shows its text.

Also you do not need to inherit `ComponentBase` in a `.razor` file.
You have two (good) options. Layouts or templates.

`Layout`(aka `MyComponentBase`)

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>
    <p>My Title</p>
    <p>My SubTitle</p>
    @Body
</div>
```

Then just use it like follows:
`MyComponent`

```
@layout MyComponentBaseLayout

<p>My Content</p>
```

The template method you almost have.
You would just change `MyComponent` to

```
<MyComponentBase>
    <p>My Content</p>
</MyComponentBase>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! As for the layout approach I have read in the MS docs that it is used for pages. I haven't tested it yet with non-page components. As for the template approach the base component also have some logic which I couldn't call directly. As for now I kept the logic in the base component and copy the layout in each child component.

Comment: If you wanted to provide an example of what you mean, I might be able to help, otherwise, if this is the answer to your question, make sure to accept it so others can see it as well.